# É possível personalizar a saída de dados do toString com lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

Na seguinte entidade:

```
public class Product {
   private String name;
   private Double price;
}
```

Seria possível implementar este toString pelo lombok?

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + String.format("%.2f", price);
 }
```

O mais próximo disso que eu achei na documentação foi esta notação:

```
@ToString(includeFieldNames = false)
```

Mas eu gostaria de poder configurar com mais liberdade, como no exemplo, o campo price.

Comment: O que te impede de simplesmente colocar o `toString()` na sua classe? O Lombok só irá gerá-lo se não encontrar alguma implementação que você mesmo já não tenha feito.

Comment: A ideia é aprender a usar o lombok

Answer (score -1):

Sim é possível, utiliza a anotação `@ToString.Exclude` nos campos que vc que excluir OU `@ToString.Include` nos que voçê quer que sejam exibidos.

O lombok vai gerar código básico para a maioria dos problemas básicos se você precisa de uma saída específica deverá fazer uma implementação específica.

Comment: Mas eu não posso incluir um format.
O @ToString.Include somente inclui os atributos, não os formata.

Comment: Nesse caso vc vai ter que implementar o toString()